# jQuery append is executed when leaving the page aswell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm experiencing a really weird behaviour. I call a function when I change to a page (jQuery Mobile event "pagebeforeshow") like so:

```
$("#library").on("pagebeforeshow", function(event){
    player.loadFiles();
});
```

The function I call looks like this:

```
Player.prototype.loadFiles = function(dir) {
    dir = dir == undefined ? 'file://~' : dir;
    if(dir.indexOf(data.lastDir) != 0){
        console.log("fired");
        $("li.item").remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://' + data.ip + ":" + data.port + '/requests/browse.xml',
            data: 'uri=' + encodeURIComponent(dir),
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                if(dir.indexOf(data.lastDir) != 0){
                var html = "";
                $(data).find("element").each(function(){
                    html += '<li class="item">' + $(this).attr('name') + "</li>";
                });
                $("#filelist").append(html);
                $(".item").addClass("ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-a ui-first-child ui-last-child")
            }   
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            alert("fail")
        }
    });
    data.lastDir = dir;
}
```

}

Now it works fine if I visit the page for the first time. It appends the listitems to the ul #filelist and sets the variables right. Now when I leave the page it adds them again. The "fired" is not shown in the console though. If I visit the page again, they aren't added again, but if I leave it again they are. I can't figure out, why it's behaving like this and would be thankful for any tips!

stiller_leser

Comment: do you have duplicate ids? try `$(document).off('pagebeforeshow').on('pagebeforeshow', '#library', function () { ... });`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I ended up with removing all li from the DOM and adding them again. It might not be optimal, but for now it does work. Will test your solution as soon as I find some time